# unable to push docker Image net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken:

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-image

i want to push a docker image to a private cloud. I use a VM with CentOS on that.
At first i tag the image:

```
docker image tag e68b8e3c115f 172.16.19.148:5000/dockercitoolstack_nexus:nexus.v01
```

and tried to push that image:

```
docker image push 172.16.19.148:5000/dockercitoolstack_nexus:nexus.v01
```

but i get this Error:

> net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: write tcp
>   192.168.19.129:59254->172.16.19.148:5000: write: connection reset by peer

i created a deamon.json file and added `{"max-concurrent-uploads": 1}`, restart docker and tried to push the image again but the same Error.

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Tagging an image is meant to be like `username/repo:tag`.

In your case the tag starts with an IP address and port `172.16.19.148:5000`, which is unusual, this part is supposed to be your username or organization name.

**Try using a character name instead of an IP address.** I tried tagging and pushing an image with an IP address like you did, and it did not work for me either.

Comment: Hi,
i don't think that is the issue. Because that works with another Image which has smaller size.